# dns lan internet name resolution

Tags: domain-name-system

What is the approach of configuring a internal DNS server to perform name resolution outside of it's scope ? The internal one will handle requests for the local network, but how to configure it to resolve google.com and other internet facing sites ? Creating a forwarder ? Root hints ? what's more secure or how to secure it ? Definitely i don't want my internal DNS to be exposed to the internet.

thanks

Comment: What DNS server and OS are you using

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by not wanting your "internal DNS to be exposed to the Internet"?

Answer (score 0):

Allowing your internal DNS server to query external DNS servers is not an issue at all, and actually common practice as it wouldn't be wise to need two different DNS servers.

The only thing to ensure your internal DNS server's security is to block its access from the outside, ideally by blocking port 53 connections from entering your network in the firewall.